# ListView inside Fragment android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

Im having trouble with implementing list view inside a fragment.

the xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/jo_logo" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

simple ImageView and afterwards the list view.
I've already tried to implement:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, viewList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

where viewList is View[], on the onCreateView function.
seems that it's not working that way inside fragment.
thing is i need that the first view will be ImageView and second one is ListView, and all inside the Fragment.

please help, thank in advance, udi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout xml change `android:id="@+id/listView1"` to `android:id="@android:id/list"` otherwise the `ListActivity` / `ListFragment` won't find your `ListView`.

Comment: thing is i'm not using ListActivity / ListFragment because i need that the first view will be ImageView and afterwards the list itselfs

Comment: You can still use ListActivity or ListFragment. But if you don't, then how are you using the `setListAdapter()` method?

Comment: yes you are right, i actually want to use:
listView.setadapter

Comment: I've changed to ListFragment and the id to list, and when i load the tab it changed the whole fragment to the list without the image

Comment: Now you only have to play with the layout weights, I will look up in a moment how can you show both in the same layout.

Comment: In my application I use the exact same layout as you inside a ListFragment. The same width and height values, the same weight and it works just fine.